# Why is not $ needed between the names of two last columns

Tags: sas

I can't get why there isn't $ between Age and Weight like there is for others
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXDbb.png)

And Why the missing value is denoted by blank in row 2 but period(.) in row 4
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuVPp.png)

Please help with such questions, I'm new to SAS and it's so miserable when I asked my colleagues, and nobody was willing to answer...

Answer (score 2):

The `$` after name and gender indicates that those variables are character variables. The other variables are numeric variables. Those are the only 2 data types in SAS.

Missing values for character variables are blanks while missing values for numeric variables are shown with a period.

Answer (score 0):

The $ modifier in a INPUT statement let's SAS know that it should treat the preceding variable as CHARACTER instead of numeric.  It is only needed when you have not previously already told SAS that the variable is character, because the default assumption is that a variable is numeric.

The normal character informat, $, which is what your code used because it did not specify any other informat for NAME or SEX, will convert a single period into blanks, which is how SAS stores an empty character value.  If you want SAS to input a single period as an actual single period you would need to use the $CHAR informat instead.  So if you modified the input statement like this:

```
input name $ sex :$char1. age weight ;
```

then the value of SEX would be the one byte string `'.'` (since the width of the informat gave SAS better information about what length to use to define the variable)  instead of the current 8 character string of blanks `'        '`.

The normal way to display a missing numeric variable is as a single period.  You can change to have it display some other single character instead by changing the setting of the MISSING option.  For example to have the missing values of AGE print as blank also you could add this OPTIONS statement before you print it.

```
options missing=' ';
```